# Codemirror adding keywords on the fly for syntax highlight

Tags: codemirror

I am currently adding a new language mode in CodeMirror for my current project. This is a proprietary language in which user can create a new keyword. Basically I am trying to update existing keyword list at the runtime and my syntax highlighter can pick this new keyword.

```
var mode = editor.doc.modeOption;
        if(mode === "dmsrl") mode = "text/dmsrl";
        var keyWords = CodeMirror.resolveMode(mode).keywords;
        keyWords[x]=true;
```

I am currently trying to add new keyword like above, but somehow the list is not getting updated and new keyword is unavailable in my tokebase() method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redefine hintOptions object, that pass to Codemirror's init function and than building hints in your specific hint addon with this data. Just try this

```
cm.setOption("hintOptions", { "keywords" : ["k1", "k2"] });
```

Look at first in sql-hint for example ([link](http://codemirror.net/mode/sql/?mime=text/x-sql)):

```
cm.setOption("hintOptions", { "tables" : ["k1", "k2"] });
```

For sql-mode this is not heavy operation

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to reach the same goal as yours but with some more degree of freedom, consisting in inputting a container, which I can re-define along the run.

1) Put the following code into a file custom.mode.js, to be loaded from your web page

```
var _glob_keywords = [ [ "key1", "keyword1" ],
                       [ "key2", "keyword2" ]
                     ] ;

var cm_custom_check_stream_fn = function( stream )
{
    for( var _i = 0 ; _i < _glob_keywords.length ; _i++ )
    {
        if ( stream.match( _glob_keywords[_i][0] ) ) return _glob_keywords[_i][1] ;
    }
    return "" ;
}

CodeMirror.defineMode("custom.mode", function()
{
    return {
    token: function(stream,state)
            {
                var _ret = cm_custom_check_stream_fn( stream ) ;
                if ( _ret.length > 0 ) return _ret ;
                else { stream.next(); return null; }
            }
           };
});
```

This code will be automatically embedded into the Codemirror object to dynamically handle the input in the textbox.
Example: if "key1" is found, then "keyword1" is returned.

We assume that "keyword1", "keyword2" refer to entries inside a custom css definitions file, as explained in the codemirror documentation, that is,

```
.cm-keyword1 { color:#8BA8C4; }
.cm-keyword2 { color:lime; }
```

Hope it helps!